# How can I access my Mater Page's radtabstrip?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a master page with a radtabstrip I use as my main navigation. In a content page I'd like to be able to disable/enable a tab from that strip. I've tried using findControl but I think it's returning null. Here's my code:

```
  RadTabStrip menuStrip = (RadTabStrip)Master.FindControl("tabMain");
  menuStrip.FindTabByText("Lookup Table").Enabled = true;    //null reference error occurs
```

Fairly simple, but I'm guessing referencing an object like a radTreeStrip isn't the same as a label or textbox..any ideas?

EDIT:

I actually got it to work by making a function on my master page and calling it from the content page. However, what I REALLY need is to access the master page from a page that is not implementing the master page. Would that be possible? Or is there a way to include the master page but not show it's contents? –

Answer (score 0):

You must first select the `Page.Master` and convert it to a `MasterPage`; next you load the control using `FindControl`, then convert it to a `RadTabStrip`, like so:

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Dim menuStrip As RadTabStrip = CType(CType(Page.Master, MasterPage).FindControl("tabMain"), RadTabStrip)
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
Proected void Page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  RadTabStrip menuStrip = (RadTabStrip)((MasterPage)Page.Master).FindControl("tabMain")
}
```

***EDIT:***

If you want the same `RadWindow` to be used across multiple pages, make sure you make a different aspx page and add its URL inside the `NavigateUrl` of the RadWindow.

Below is a link from **Telerik** that displays info about the `RadWindow` and its `NavigateUrl`:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/contenttemplatevsnavigateurl/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: I actually got it to work by making a function on my master page and calling it from the content page. However, what I REALLY need is to access the master page from a page that is not implementing the master page. Would that be possible? Or is there a way to include the master page but not show it's contents?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think that's possible. What are you trying to achieve? If you want a self programmed control to be accessible by multiple pages, you should create a Web User Control

Comment: I guess the simply way to put it is: Can I access a master page without having to include it in the main page (not a content page).

Comment: You can link to it, or fetch it by http, but you can't access its contents, at least not as far as I know ...

Comment: If you want to access something in a MasterPage that is not Control-based (like a function or something), just include it in a separate class.  If you want to access a MasterPage's Control, there's no valid reason you wouldn't be a child of the MasterPage.

Comment: Well, the problem is I have a popup window which is itself another page. It appears inside a radWindow declared in the masterPage. However I don't want the tabMenu to appear inside the window. So if I can include the master page but hide its contents, something like that might work

Comment: Just have the popup display a page that doesn't inherit from the Master, have it be a stand-alone, normal ASPX page.

Comment: sockfd. That's how I have it a button is pressed in my menu on the master page and a radWindow pop up and opens another aspx page inside of it. I thought using previospage property would work but no dice. The telerik example shows how to close the window from another aspx but not how to access the page where the radWindow is..

Comment: If you need to communicate between pages, I suggest using the `Session`.

Comment: Maybe this is something for you: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/returning-values-to-parent-page-from-rad-window.aspx#962526 This sample demonstrates how to pass the return values from a radwindow to its parent page

Comment: @WillTuttle ***Please kindly create a separate question if you have a issue regarding RadWindow which becomes totally different topic from original question.***